# Spring Security: does "edit" role implicitly assume that a user can read?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I am implementing authorization for a REST service using Spring Security. I have roles that can be grouped in role groups.

In particular, I have `VIEW_EMPLOYEE` and `EDIT_EMPLOYEE` roles.

I have `EmployeeController` with two endpoints: `readEmployee` and `updateEmployee`. The `updateEmployee` endpoint is secured with the `EDIT_EMPLOYEE` role via the next Spring Security annotation: `@Secured(EDIT_EMPLOYEE)`.

My question is about `readEmployee`: should I secure it with *both* `VIEW_EMPLOYEE` and `EDIT_EMPLOYEE` roles? Or just with `VIEW_EMPLOYEE`?

```
@Secured({VIEW_EMPLOYEE, EDIT_EMPLOYEE /* do I need it here? */})
@GetMapping("/employees/{id}")
Employee readEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
    // ...
}

@Secured(EDIT_EMPLOYEE)
@PostMapping("/employees/{id}")
Employee updateEmployee(@PathVariable Long id, Employee employee) {
    // ...
}
```

The first approach looks more natural to me: on the UI of my application, in order to edit an employee, I should first read it. This means that `EDIT_EMPLOYEE` role should implicitly allow to read employee as well.

On the other hand, the second approach (with just `VIEW_EMPLOYEE`) looks more maintainable: in future, every time I create a new `read*` endpoint, I should not keep in mind that I need to add an `EDIT_*` role to it as well.

Is there a best practice on what approach to use?

Comment: Look at it this way READ_ONLY_USER and ADMIN_USER, it doesn't make much sense if an ADMIN_USER can't view an employ record. For me, ADMIN_USER should have access to both but READ_ONLY_USER limited to read-only.

Comment: @justMe, thank you for your suggestion. That is really a useful way to look at the problem. That means, the first approach is more reasonable.